# Should std::list be deprecated?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, containers, doubly-linked-list

According to Bjarne Stroustrup's [slides](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf) from his [Going Native 2012 keynote](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style), insertion and deletion in a `std::list` are terribly inefficient on modern hardware:

[image: vector vs list]

> Vector beats list massively for insertion and deletion

If this is indeed true, what use cases are left for `std::list`? Shouldn't it be deprecated then?

Comment: non-invalidateable iterators and references, as long as that particular element is not removed.

Comment: You are assuming that the only reason one would choose a list is for insertion performance. In fact i would consider storage persisyance to be the main reason one *should* choose a list.

Comment: I also question those results. Insertion and deletion from a linked-list should be `O(1)` whereas it is `O(n)` for a vector.

Comment: It still wins in some categories, especially for large amounts of data: http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/

Comment: I'd say no, because a list is still perfectly good for using with small numbers of elements.

Comment: @Mysticial: The cache beats that complexity handily for small data sizes.

Comment: @DeadMG Although 100k elements isn't exactly small...

Comment: The slide doesn't even say what a sequence test is, so it's difficult to say that.

Comment: Keep in mind you can change the allocator for list to guarantee locality, which I've done from time to time to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: that graph is unacceptable: it contains no details about the sequencing operation and data type nor on the hardware. Really you want to vary all those parameters.

Comment: @Walter The graph is really just an invitation to look at the linked slides.

Comment: The graph involves the sum of two operations.  Finding the element to remove, and removing it.  Finding is O(n) in both cases.  Removing is O(1) for list and O(n) for vector, but vector's operations have a constant factor under half of list's.  The test is valid because you usually have to find the element to erase before erasing it.  It does not obsolete list because sometimes this is not true.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Vector and list solve different problems.  List provides the guarantee that iterators never become invalidated as you insert and remove other elements. Vector doesn't make that guarantee.

It's not all about performance. So the answer is no. List should not be deprecated.

### Edit

Beyond this, C++ isn't designed to work solely on "modern hardware."  It is intended to be useful across a much wider range of hardware than that.  I'm a programmer in the financial industries and I use C++, but other domains such as embedded devices, programmable controllers, heart-lung machines and myriad others are just as important.  The C++ language should not be designed *solely* with the needs of certain domains and the performance of certain classes of hardware in mind.  Just because *I* might not use a list doesn't mean it should be deprecated from the language.

Comment: Though, unfortunately, `list` did got a bashing when the standardese guys decided that `size` had to be O(1). `splice` was one of the best reasons to use a list before, and now it's not as useful, to the point that should you need it you're better off crafting your own container :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. C++11 added `std::forward_list` to fill this niche.

Comment: It's not true that `std::list` won't invalidate iterators. All iterators that point at the deleted node are invalidated. Effectively it means that you have to keep a list of iterators, just like you would do in the case of `std::vector`.

`std::list` is slow on pretty much any hardware, not just modern. You'd be hard-pressed to find a combination of a use case and hardware where `std::list` outperforms `std::vector` in either memory or execution speed.

Answer (score 8):

Whether a vector outperforms a list or not also depends on the type of the elements. For example, for `int` elements vector is indeed very fast as most of the data fits inside the CPU cache and SIMD instructions can be used for the data copying. So the O(n) complexity of vector doesn't have much impact.

But what about larger data types, where copying doesn't translate to a stream operation, and instead data must be fetched from all over the place? Also, what about hardware that doesn't have large CPU caches and possibly also lacks SIMD instructions? C++ is used on much more than just modern desktop and workstation machines. Deprecating std::list is out of the question.

What Stroustrup is saying in that presentation is that before you pick std::list for your data, you should make sure that it's the right choice for *your particular situation*. In other words, benchmark and profile. It definitely doesn't say you should always pick std::vector.

Answer (score 3):

No, and especially not based on one particular graph. There are instances where list will perform better than vector. See: http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/

And that's ignoring the non-performance differences, as others have mentioned.

Bjarne's point in that talk wasn't that you shouldn't use list. It was that people make too many assumptions about list's performance that often turn out to be wrong. He was simply justifying the stance that vector should always be your default go-to container type unless you actually find a need for the performance or other semantic characteristics of lists.

Comment: The benchmark you provided demonstrates that `std::list` only has a chance against `std::vector` when the size of the element is large. At which point you are better off allocating your elements on the heap and storing `std::unique_ptr` in a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. std::list is a different data structure. Comparing different data structure is good indication of its properties, advantages or disadvantages. But each data structure has its advantage.

Answer (score 0):

`std::list` is a deque, it has `push_front()` and `pop_front()`. It still has a niche role as such, though it may not be the best choice for a deque.

`std::list` does not reallocate memory, while `std::vector` may. Sometimes you don't want an item to move in memory (e.g. a stackful coroutine).

Linked lists are related to tree data structures. Both contain links. If we deprecate `std::list`, then what about tree-based containers?