# How to add elements to a sorted list ...? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I just had my first contact with std::vector and now I want to change my bad habit of using plain C-style arrays. I found that std::list is the container to use when it comes to sorting. However, I am not 100% how to accomplish the following:

I am doing some calculations whose outcome depends on two indices (i and j). In the end I am only interested in the 100 smallest results (not necessarily 100, but for sure much smaller than my total number of calculated values, m*n in the below code).

```
const int L = 100;
int i_list[L];
int j_list[L];
double value_list[L];

for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
        double x = doSomeCalculations(i,j);
        insertTheValueAndIndices(i,j,x,i_list,j_list,value_list);
    }
}
```

After completion, value_list should contain the 100 smallest values (increasing order) and i_list / j_list the corresponding indices. I have a working version of the "insertValuesAndIndices()", but there I use plain arrays and the most inefficient way of inserting new values. While writing I realize that i actually have 2 distinct questions:

1. The number of computed values (m*n) is by far bigger than the number I want to keep in the list, thus simply keeping all values and sorting only once in the end is not really an option. On the other hand, I need the results in the right order only in the end, so maybe there is a way of sorting the list only once. Is there any "standard" clever and efficient way do to this kind of sorting?
2. Even if I could store all results and do the sorting afterwards, I am not sure how to use the std::list.sort() to get the arrays of indices in the right order. What came to my mind is to define some class containing the result and the two indices, put those elements in a list and then use a comparator that checks only the value to do the sorting. However, maybe there is a more straightforward way to do the same?

Cheers & Thanks in advance

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) can be sorted with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: "std::list is the container to use when it comes to sorting" -- Eh? Why do you say that? Any sequence container can be sorted.

Comment: [Should std::list be deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779719/should-stdlist-be-deprecated)

Comment: And of course, you don't really need to sort anyway.  Just use `std::lower_bound` to find the insertion point.  In this way, you don't have to let the vector grow to more values than you need.

Comment: @Drop No.  There are still cases where it is the only container which will do.  Think about iterator validity when inserting.

Comment: @JamesKanze It's not my question, but what was asked in the linked topic. Just an existence of this question shows how bad `std::list` in practice (vs theory).

Comment: @FredLarson Here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/ i read that "Lists are sequence containers that allow constant time insert and erase operations anywhere within the sequence". As I understood, vectors are only optimized to have efficient adding of elements at the end, thus I thought its more efficient to use std::list instead of std::vector when sorting

Comment: @tobi303 The problem is *getting to* the kth element of a list requires iterating over it (O(k)), and that is more expensive than erasing from a vector.  There are extremely rare corner cases where you want a list, and this is not one of them.

Answer (score 6):

First, you probably don't want `std::list`, but `std::vector`.
Then use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) to find where to insert, and if the
resulting vector contains more than the number of elements
you're interested in, `std::vector<>::pop_back` to get rid of
the extra one.

Comment: [c++.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) says: "Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, inserting elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container to relocate all the elements that were after position to their new positions. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence containers (such as list or forward_list)." Most of the time I will not insert at the end, so I dont understand, why I should use a vector and not a list...

Comment: @tobi303 Because the passage you quote is false on a modern machine.  You can copy an awful lot in the time it takes to do one allocation, and after the copy, all of the data will still be contiguous, which reduces cache misses.  Add to that the fact that you need a random access iterator to do a lower_bound, and that's another strike against `std::list`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you comments. As my post does not state a single well defined question, but it was rather demonstrating my ignorance of how to solve my problem ;), I want to post my conclusions and a working example...

First of all, thanks for clarifying, that "std::list is the container to use when it comes to sorting"
is not true. As pointed out e.g. by James Kanze, std::vector does the job as well. Second, I really do not have to "sort" the vector if I just "insert" new values at the right place. Further, there was no objection towards my idea of how to get the indices also sorted and here is my solution:

```
#include <cfloat>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct MyValue{
    MyValue(double v,int f,int s):value(v),first(f),second(s){}
    double value;
    int first;
    int second;
};
bool compareValues(const MyValue a,const MyValue b){return a.value < b.value;}
void insertMyValue(std::vector<MyValue>* v,MyValue x,int maxSize){
    v->insert(std::lower_bound(v->begin(),v->end(),x,compareValues),x);
    if (v->size()>maxSize){v->erase(v->end()-1);}
}
void main(){
    const int imax = 10;
    const int jmax = 10;
    const int Nmax = 30;
    std::vector<MyValue> results;
    results.reserve(Nmax+1);
    // Fill the vector
    for (int i=0;i<imax;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<jmax;j++){
            double result = i*(j+0.1);
            insertMyValue(&results,MyValue(result,i,j),Nmax);
        }
    }
    // Print it
    for (std::vector<MyValue>::iterator it = results.begin();it<results.end();it++){
        cout << (*it).first << " " << (*it).second << " " << (*it).value << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is a bad idea.

Instead use a `std::vector<int> buffer(count);` to store a `std::make_heap`.

Then do:

```
template<class T>
void add_element( std::vector<T>& heap, T element, size_t size ) {
  heap.push_back(element);
  std::push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
  while (heap.size() > size) {
    std::pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
    heap.pop_back();
  }
}
```

which takes a heap in the form of a `vector` (an empty `vector` is a heap), and adds an element, then pops any elements more than the heap limit.

This will work for any `T` that has an `operator<`.  There are custom comparator versions of `push_heap` and `pop_heap` as well.