# Is there something like a "default comparator"?

Tags: c++, compare

I wrote a template that wraps a std::vector to make sure the vector is always sorted:

```
template <typename T> class SortedVector{
public:    
    SortedVector(bool (*comparator)(T,T)=DefaultComparator<T>){
        this->comparator = comparator;
    }
    void insertValue(T newElement){            
        vect.insert(std::lower_bound(
           vect.begin(),vect.end(),newElement,comparator),newElement);
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> vect;
    bool (*comparator)(T,T);
};
```

I want to be able to use a custom comparators, but in most cases it will be ok to simply use `T`'s `<` operator. However, I did not find any better way than to use this

```
template <typename T> bool DefaultComparator(T a,T b){return a<b;}
```

as the default parameter.

Maybe it is a stupid question... Isn't there a nicer way to get the same without defining my own `DefaultComparator`?

I cannot use C++11.

Comment: Use `std::less`. If you don't have it, writing your own one is very simple.

Comment: A variant I like is a `vector` that is sorted only when people read from it.  Writing to it doesn't sort it.  So you keep track of a "highwater" mark of where the prefix is sorted, and on read you first sort the "unsorted" part, then do a merge with the "sorted" part.  If your use case is "add a bunch of data, then examine it lots", and not "edit, examine, edit, examine", this results in really good performance.  Your implementation has really poor performance on both.

Comment: @Yakk My actual application for this class is that I have to run through millions of elements (far to many and too big to fit into any reasonable vector) and keep only the `N` lowest ones. Thus, first filling and then sorting is not an option or it would result in something overly complicated as anyhow the application is slowed down by reading this elements from a file rather than anything else.

Comment: @Yakk actually, this question is a follow up of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675908/how-to-add-elements-to-a-sorted-list-c). Would be nice if you could comment/answer on that question, as this one here was really only about the comparator.

Comment: @tobi303 as I mentioned there, using a sorted vector to find the lowest 100 items is also a bad idea.  It is `O( m n lg n )` where `m` is the total elements, `n` is the limit.  You can do it in `O( m lg n )`.

Comment: @Yakk If this O(whatever) makes less than 1% or my total runtime, then honestly i dont care if I can make it O(log whatever).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a standard function template to do what you want; but there is a standard function *class* template, `std::less`. If you were to use a generic function object, rather than restricting yourself to a function pointer, then it's easy to specify that as a default:

```
template <typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T> > 
class SortedVector{
public:    
    SortedVector(Comparator comparator = Comparator()){
        this->comparator = comparator;
    }
    void insertValue(T newElement){
        // lower_bound accepts any suitable function object, so no change needed
        vect.insert(std::lower_bound(
           vect.begin(),vect.end(),newElement,comparator),newElement);
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> vect;
    Comparator comparator;
};
```

Comment: Note: `std::less` is available since C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought that as well but it's [not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) so...

Comment: @black: The version without the default argument is marked "until C++14". It was available in C++98, and in the STL before that. Now it's been replaced with a (backward-compatible) version that deduces the argument types if you don't specify them, and behaves exactly as before if you do.

Comment: After some time, I am working again on this issue and now I am wondering if it really is necessary to have the Comparator type as template parameter, when anyway it will be a `bool (*Comparator)(const T&,const T&)` and the actual instance is passed to the constructor. Is it possible to add this as typedef to the class and skip the template parameter? (I tried, but then the compiler complains about the `T` in `Comparator comparator = std::less<T>` in the constructors parameter list.)

Comment: @tobi303: It's generally better to use a function class like `std::less`, rather than a function pointer, so that the function call is direct and inlinable. You could hard-code the type to be a function pointer if you particularly dislike templates for some reason; but performance would probably suffer, and you'd need to provide a function, not `std::less`, for the default comparator.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding on my side. When I used the template (just as you posted it) with a function pointer as comparator I had to provide an extra `typedef bool (*Comparator) (const MyElement&,const MyElement&)`. At first glance this seems a bit circumstantial, because I have to provide the type (typedef as template parameter) and the actual instance (to the constructor). However, when using a functor, suddenly it makes sense, because in that case passing the actual instance to the constructor is optional.

Answer (score 3):

You can use class template [`std::less<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) as default.

```
template <typename T, typename C=std::less<T>>
class SortedVector
{
public:    
  SortedVector(C cmp=C()) : comparator(cmp)
  {
  }
  void insertValue(T newElement){            
    vect.insert(std::lower_bound(
       vect.begin(),vect.end(),newElement,comparator),newElement);
}
private:
    std::vector<T> vect;
    C comparator;
};
```